# Blender Shading problem

Tags: rendering, shaders

I got weird problem with shading in my Blender. Anyone know how to fix this? Rendering, texutre and material looks good. Earlier I tried reinstall but nothing special happened.
[image]

Comment: If you have an AMD GPU, it's related to your drivers. The most recent Adrenalin drivers cause this problem in blender. Try enabling "High Quality Normals" under `Render Properties > Performance`

Comment: I got it! It was High Quality Normals (as you said). Thanks!